# How to configure Meteor Oplog Tailing on a Sharded Mongo DB

Tags: meteor

As we're developing a greedy real-time monitoring application on Meteor, we reached the limit of our single MongoDB instance.

We migrated the DB to a sharded cluster with 2 shards for now, but we might expand up to 6 shards. (I have 2 BladeE chassis with 28 servers)

**How do we configure Meteor Oplog Tailing on a mongo db cluster with sharding enabled?**

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

**Now there is a good news :) You can use sharded MongoDB database with Meteor easily with a bit of tweaking**

Although Meteor core development team hasn't yet add Oplog Tailing support for sharding to [their RoadMap](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/Roadmap.md), the workaround is so simple. You just add these 2 Meteor packages: `cultofcoders:redis-oplog` and `disable-oplog`, add another `Redis` server, tweak your code a bit and you are good to go.

The reason why Oplog Tailing doesn't work with sharded MongoDB database is just because core development team hasn't yet planed to support it. In fact, it's now possible to add support for sharded database. If you add a bunch of new records and read the Oplogs with tailable cursors from all shards, you will notice that MognoDB balancer will move data, lets say, from `shard01` to `shard02` where record id `0001` got removed from `shard01` and added to `shard02`. This situation seems to be confusing for Meteor as it doesn't know whether records are actually removed/added by users or by MongoDB balancer. However there is a way to know whether users or MongoDB balancer removed/added the data because we can distinguish by `fromMigrate` flag — read more about this at [MongoDB official site blog](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/tailing-mongodb-oplog-sharded-clusters) — so what we can do for now is to wait for update from core development team or work around with few tricks.

And the most promising workaround I've found so far is Meteor package called `cultofcoders:redis-oplog`. It's opensource and available on [Github](https://github.com/cult-of-coders/redis-oplog) (Please check up their repository for full documentation. It's very-easy-to-use). The idea behind this package is to use another `Redis` server as `pub` and `sub` system — it doesn't store any data. it's just for `pub` and `sub` — instead of Meteor's which heavily rely on Oplog. This way, we don't have to worry about Oplog for sharded database that Meteor hasn't yet supported. `Redis` is mature and has been being used in production by many big companies. It's fully compatible with Meteor and you don't have to change the way you use Meteor. However you have to tweak your code a bit when updating collection's data in order to publish changes to `Redis`, and then the package `cultofcoders:redis-oplog` will handle the rest.

Comment: I actually tried this. I sharded a DB on MongoDB Atlas and used `redis-oplog`. `redis-oplog` indeed worked and things stayed snappy and reactive,  BUT I did not measure an increase in performance out of Mongo. So I don't think Meteor is working with the shards correctly. I added the 7 shard URL to Meteor (which looks like a normal Mongo URL with 7 URLS instead of 3).  My app was bottlenecking at the Mongo level (visible in Meteor APM (Kadira)) and the results were still the same after sharding. So not sure it's working correctly.

Comment: @evolross I don't think you have to add 7 MongoDB shards' URLs to you Meteor app. Have you tried adding `mongos` URL to `env` instead of shards' one ? MongoDB official site said that we should connect to `mongos` in order to interact with the sharded database, and avoid interacting with the shards directly. Regarding to the bottleneck at MongoDB level, I don't think it's a problem with Meteor. It's most likely that you forgot adding necessary indexes or forgot passing `shard key` in queries which cause MongoDB to query every single document on all shards...and here comes performance issue.

Comment: Is there anything in the Meteor docs about `shard key` or `mongos`? Have you personally got it to work and can prove the shards were working?  And I have all my indexes and have written many topics in the Meteor forums about optimization.  It's the way my app works and the amount of users I have simultaneously.

Comment: @evolross Meteor doesn't have docs about `shard key` and `mongos` as it hasn't yet officially supported sharded database. In fact, Meteor doesn't have to know if the database was sharded or not because we will have Meteor connect to `mongos` and then `mongos` will take care of the clustered database. Indeed, you don't need to read `shard key` and `mongos` on Meteor docs because it's already there on MongoDB official site. I haven't yet personally got it to work as I'm now developing this kind of application like you. if I finish developing my app, I will let you know.

Comment: When I get a chance to give it a shot, I'll let you know. Thanks for the comments, it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Meteor does not yet support sharded mongoDB setups with > 1 shard: https://forums.meteor.com/t/mongodb-sharding-and-livequery/3712